# Is there a way to output overall/high level jest coverage report to a single html (not external js/css/image), pdf or jpg file

Tags: jestjs

We want to send high level jest coverage report email on every build. Is there a way to output report to a single html (not external js/css/image), pdf or jpg file.

Answer (score 0):

A puppeteer script solved this for us

```
const path = require('path');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const rimraf = require('rimraf');
const screenshot = 'unit-test-coverage.png';
const url = 'file://' + path.resolve(__dirname, '../../coverage/lcov-report/index.html');

// remove existing screenshot
rimraf.sync(screenshot);

// generate screenshot
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
    await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });

    await page.screenshot({
        path: screenshot,
        fullPage: true
    });

    await browser.close();
})();
```